# What is the concept behind cloudshare.com website

Tags: cloud, virtual, cloud-hosting

I am using [cloudshare](http://cloudshare.com) for practicing sharepoint. Really it is amazing. With in seconds the environment will create. How they made it. What concept is hidden behind that. Nearly 1000's of users will use the cloudshare virtual environments. How they are providing such wonderful environments? They says every thing is cloud, that means it is depends on cloud technology like azure? Can any one tell me how it is working??

Answer (score 0):

The service runs out of Terremark's flagship NAP of the America's datacenter, a Tier IV facility.  It now also runs on datacenters in APAC and EMEA.

Azure is an amazing service as well, but is currently not mature enough on a few different specifications.  E.g. "There's really no Azure-specific mechanism for things like system restore points, as that's within the OS itself." see serverfault link: https://serverfault.com/questions/531673/how-do-i-backup-a-windows-azure-virtual-machine.

I also work at CloudShare, and would be glad to answer any questions. Ping me @ alex@cloudshare.com

Answer (score -1):

Full disclosure: I'm from CloudShare. I joined the company 7 months ago and I asked the same question. I can tell you today that the solution was built from day one expecting zero IT infrastructure knowledge from our users.

Comment: @Ezibotech I am not able to understand your answer.. :(